# My i/p is "Welcome to the class" and my o/p should be "ssa lc eh t ot emoc leW" using stringbuilder

Tags: java, arrays, string

Am converting the String to array to reverse it. How should I proceed to get the desired output.[image: Source Code]

Comment: Please post the actual code, not an image. Also, this has nothing to do with javascript.

Comment: Copy pasting code is easy than taking a snap of your code and putting it here.

Answer (score 1):

[StringBuilder#reverse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()) shall do the job for you

> Causes this character sequence to be replaced by the reverse of the
> sequence. If there are any surrogate pairs included in the sequence,
> these are treated as single characters for the reverse operation.
> Thus, the order of the high-low surrogates is never reversed. Let n be
> the character length of this character sequence (not the length in
> char values) just prior to execution of the reverse method. Then the
> character at index k in the new character sequence is equal to the
> character at index n-k-1 in the old character sequence.
>
> Note that the
> reverse operation may result in producing surrogate pairs that were
> unpaired low-surrogates and high-surrogates before the operation. For
> example, reversing "\uDC00\uD800" produces "\uD800\uDC00" which is a
> valid surrogate pair.

Answer (score 0):

These are the two simple ways i can think of to reverse the string...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder r = new StringBuilder("Welcome to the class");
        for (int i = r.length(); i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(r.charAt(i - 1));
        }
        System.out.println("\n" + r.reverse());//this is also another way to do it.
}
```

> NOTE: "**r.reverse()**" modifies the original StringBuilder object.

Comment: Re your NOTE ... just about every operation on a `StringBuilder` modifies it.  That's the point of using a `StringBuilder` rather than a `String`.

Comment: @abishek, the problem am facing is with the space in between the reverse order

Comment: @VisaaliSundaram could you be more detailed.... your question doesn't state any issue dealing with spaces... and the above code prints your string in the reverse order correctly only.

Comment: @StephenC thanks for mentioning it. learnt something new today...

Comment: @abishek, for eg; my i/p is "My name" and my o/p is "eman yM" with ur code. But i need the o/p as "em an y M".

Comment: @VisaaliSundaram is there any pattern to your required output?? without it answering your question would be futile attempt....

Comment: @Abhishek - My comment was really directed at your *"Be careful when using it"* warning ... that you have since deleted.  Why warn about a property of `StringBuilder` operations which is the real reason for using the class in the first place?

Comment: @StephenC i had found out of about this property of StringBuilder while i was trying to solve this question. Previously i wasn't aware of this. Therefore my findings were carried over to this answer.

Comment: @Abhishek -  Oh.  My apologies.  I had assumed you were being sarcastic.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution: 
      StringBuilder r=new StringBuilder("Welcome to the class");

```
     String[] parts = r.reverse().toString().split(" ");
     String finalValue="";
StringBuffer str1 ;
     for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) 
     {
         if(parts[i].length()>2)
         {
           str1=new StringBuffer (parts[i]);
             str1.insert((int)Math.ceil((parts[i].length())/2)+1,' ');
           parts[i]=str1.toString();

         }
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) 
     {
         finalValue +=parts[i] +" ";
     }
    System.out.println(finalValue.trim());
```

if you see clearly, it puts a space between each word.. take example of welcome. in reverse it would be emoclew.. which is 7 letter word.. divide in two half emoc lew